# Regex To Limit Upper and Lower Limit For Numbers

Tags: regex

I am trying to run a regex validation for a text box that would take an input in a format mm/dd.  I got enough help for the structure part i.e. `^\d{2}/\d{2}?` but is there a way to limit the max value and min value, something like `^\d{2}(sth that requires this to be between 0 and 12)/\d{2}(sth that requires this to be between 1 and 31)?`.

Comment: That's really attempting to fit a round peg in a square hole.

Comment: Regular expressions cannot validate numbers in the way you want

Comment: Even if regex is possible but it will allow `02/30` or `09/31` etc

Comment: Okay, now that I know this isn't possible, I can look into other alternatives. I am quite certain that there would be others thinking the way I was and knowing "Not possible" is better than thinking "Is it possible?" Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @anubhava Try my solution, shouldn't match those.

Comment: This type of validation will not catch scenarios where the day of the month is 1 to 12 and the User is used to a non-US time format.  He might enter 4th of February and you interpret it as April 2nd.  You will need to detect the browser locale before applying the regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not meant to be done with regex!

But well, I did because I can.

Here is a solution:

```
/^(?!0?2\/3[01])(?!(?:0?[469]|11)\/31)(?:\d|1[012])\/(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$/
```

You should **NEVER** use regex for this!

From what I understand, the format is `mm/dd` (month/day).

Days range from 1-31 and months from 0-12 (OP's request).
This evaluates just that.

Using a negative lookaheads, I can assure a (possible) valid date.

But seriously: kids, do not try at home!

---

**EDIT:**

As asked by the OP in a commend, here I will explain how this works:

Right at the beginning we have the `^` char.
This anchors the string at the beginning, instead of possibly starting matching from the middle of a string.

All the groups starting with `(?!)` are negative lookaheads.

What this do is that it will take a peek *ahead* to check if what is in front *doesn't* match the pattern.

Using `(?!0?2\/3[01])` will ensure that `2/30` or `2/31` *isn't* matched.
Similarly with `(?!(?:0?[469]|11)\/31)`, which ensures that `4/31`, `6/31`, `9/31` and `11/31` be used.

Using the first example (`(?!0?2\/3[01])`), there is `0?`.
That means that there is **at most** one `0`.

Still on the same example, you will see `3[01]`.
Using `[]` determines a set of characters that can be matched, in this case the characters `0` and `1`.

Using the second example (`(?!(?:0?[469]|11)\/31)`), you have the group `(?:0?[469]|11)`.
All the groups like `(?:)` are non-capturing groups.
This means that they will match but won't save the match.
This is useful for decisions, which we use with the `|`, which is used to match the pattern before or after it.
In essence, it works like an `or` operator.

So far, we only have been checking if the string isn't one of those invalid dates.
And now, we will validate the date format using `(?:\d|1[012])\/(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])$`.
This parts ensures that the format is correct and within the limits.
The `(?:\d|1[012])` bit matches any number from `0` to `9` (the `\d`, which is the same as `[0-9]`) **or** matches `10`, `11` or `12`.
Similarly, `(?:[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])` matches from `1` to `9`; or `1` or `2` followed by a number from `0` to `9` (essentially, `10` to `29`); or `30` or `31`.

To finish, we have the `$` character.
Contrarily to `^`, this will anchor to the end of the string.
Without this, `2/29 i like cookies` would match.
Without the `^`, `On 3/20, we will meet here` would also be matched.

I am not the best teacher in the world and I am not the best at explaining.
If you practice, you will see that this starts making sense.
**Any** question regarding this subject, I'm free to answer.

Comment: To the downvoter: I was fixing it! It's working now!

Comment: @HakuKalay At least tell me if this fits your needs or not, please

Comment: Accepting this as answer. Mainly for clearly stating what I was asking for isn't meant to be done with RegEx. If I had known that I wouldn't have spend hour and half looking for a possible answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ismael, could you take a moment to explain the expression? Would appreciate if you can, if you can't that's fine as well. Btw, Ismael, why is it strictly prohibited? Just because of the convoluted nature of the expression?

Comment: @HakuKalay You are welcome. The right way should be to use a date library like date.js (http://www.datejs.com/). And regex (regular expressions) are used to evaluate patterns, and not to evaluate if a value is higher than the other. As you can see, it is possible (and quite hard and sometimes buggy) but as you can also see, I had to use "hacks" (in this case, 2 lookaheads). You would never use a a knife in a gun fight, even though it might hurt anyway. Why would you evaluate dates with regex?

Comment: @HakuKalay With a little more time I will add the explanation to the question. Meanwhile, you can try to practice with it on http://regex101.com/

Comment: For the effort to write this regex +1 but I won't recommend using this :)

Comment: @anubhava I don't recommend either. As I said, date.js is a superior solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: @HakuKalay I have added an explanation on how it works. Any doubt, just ask and I will answer.